# Why is entropy growth incompatible with "deterministically computed universes"?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, quantum-computer, information, determinism

I read on Wikipedia that in his book Calculating Space, Konrad Zuse

> "proposed that the universe is being computed by some sort of cellular
>   automaton or other discrete computing machinery... and **pointed out
>   (among other things) that the classical notions of entropy and its
>   growth do not make sense in deterministically computed universes.**" ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculating_Space))

It seems difficult to find any details on Zuse's initial thought and even more so to understand that particular point about entropy, which seems quite crucial.

Hence my question, does anyone know what Zuse meant?

Comment: It's not difficult to find details, the whole book is freely available at [this page](http://people.idsia.ch/~juergen/digitalphysics.html), linked on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

He is talking about how entropy is "random" or whatever.

Entropy is sometimes said to be random in the colloquial sense, because it involves probability, and spontaneous decreases in entropy have a finite chance of occurring. But randomness is not a technical term, and the author doesn't really have grounds to make his claims.

It is a pile of nonscientific gobbledygook.

Comment: If you could please elaborate a bit, that would be appreciated.